# Passing socket.io data to vuejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, vue.js

I have an issue with passing socket.io data to vuejs element. I went through Vue documentation few times and I couldn't find solution for this. Basically, I have a data that's being sent to client via socket.io and console.log prints it perfectly. Now I wanted to use Vue to render html elements with that data, however I have an issue with passing my socket.io data to it.

In Vue documentation there's an example how to do it with static data input.

```
var example1 = new Vue({
  el: '#example-1',
  data: {
    items: [
      { message: 'Foo' },
      { message: 'Bar' }
    ]
  }
})
```

So I figured out that I need to convert my data object to string for this. I used JSON.stringify() for this.

```
var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.1.10');
socket.on('posts', function (datasocket) {
  var st = JSON.stringify(datasocket);
  var blogposts = new Vue({
    el: '#blogpost',
    data: {
      items: st
    }
  })
});
```

And HTML

```
  <div id="blogpost">
    <div v-for="item in items" class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">{{ item.post_title }}</h4>
        <p class="card-text">{{ item.post_excerpt }}</p>
        <a href="{{ item.post_link }}" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

However, Vue doesn't seem to render anything. In my console when I do console.log on **st**, I get output:

```
{"content":[{"post_title":"Post title 1","post_excerpt":"Post excerpt 1","post_link":"/post/1"},{"post_title":"Post title 2","post_excerpt":"Post excerpt 2","post_link":"/post/2"},{"post_title":"Post title 3","post_excerpt":"Post excerpt 2","post_link":"/post/3"}]}
```

So any idea how to correctly pass this data to VueJS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should put your socket connection into one of the lifecycle hook - for your case `mounted()` should work.

```
    var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.1.10');
    var blogposts = new Vue({
        el: '#blogpost',
        data: {
          items: []
        },
        mounted: function() {
          socket.on('posts', function(datasocket) {
            this.items.push(datasocket.content)
          }.bind(this))
        }

    })
```

Note: If you use arrow syntax, then you don't have to bind `this`

```
mounted: function() {
   socket.on('posts', datasocket => {
     this.items.push(datasocket.content)
   })
}
```

Btw: I don't think you need to use `JSON.stringify`

Comment: Still doesn't work, but definitely a step closer to a solution. Now I do get HTML rendered properly, only this time I get one element with {{ item.post_title }}, {{ item.post_excerpt }} etc.

Comment: What console says ? Have you removed the `JSON.stringify` ?

Comment: Console doesn't show any error in it, if that was the question. And I did try without JSON.stringify - it's still the same.

Comment: Do you have VueJS Dev Tool Chrome extension installed ? Please check there is the items array filled with any data...
Or if you want I could help you over teamviewer

Comment: I didn't know about that extension, thanks. After installing extension I got an error in a console that says that Vue cannot find targeted HTML element, even though it was there. So relocating javascript code outside head tag did the trick and there's no more console errors nor  {{ item.post_title }} and  {{ item.post_excerpt }}. But still, data isn't being shown. In my Vue console I can see data that's passed.

Comment: Could you take screenshot of Vue Dev Tool, that show contents of the `items` array ?

Comment: `data
items:Array[1]
0:"{\"content\":[{\"post_title\":\"Post title 1\",\"post_excerpt\":\"Post excerpt 1\",\"post_link\":\"/post/1\"},{\"post_title\":\"Post title 2\",\"post_excerpt\":\"Post excerpt 2\",\"post_link\":\"/post/2\"},{\"post_title\":\"Post title 3\",\"post_excerpt\":\"Post excerpt 2\",\"post_link\":\"/post/3\"}]}"`

Comment: Okay, change this `<div v-for="item in items" class="card" style="width: 20rem;">` to this `<div v-for="item in items[0].content" class="card" style="width: 20rem;">`

Comment: Thank you very much @Belmin. It does work now, but without `JSON.stringify()`, otherwise not even `v-for="item in items[0].content"` make difference.

Comment: Well it seems that `items[0]` is affecting reactivity of Vue element. When **socket.io** pushes new data, vue can't show changes, as the new data set has different index number i.e. `items[1]`, `items[2]`. So parsing socket.io data as intended is still a problem. Any tips?

Comment: Could you post screenshot of your data structure ?

Comment: My **db.json** is here https://pastebin.com/bQW6LnRr and Vue Dev extension screenshots http://imgur.com/a/GPi4v

Comment: That's a bit strange data structure, but you can have nested loop, check this    http://jsbin.com/nixewufoqe/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @MerkisL Or you could even try to do this `this.items.push(JSON.parse(datasocket.content))`

Comment: I'm afraid `JSON.parse()` won't do anything as `datasocket.content` is already an object.

Comment: @MerkisL then go without JSON.parse or with 2 loops...thsi data structure confuse me a bit - I posted solution with 2 loops in one of prev comments.

Comment: Just wanted to let everyone know that I managed to solve the problem. As I said few replies before, problem is that new socket data creates new set of arrays each time and that kills reactivity as you have different index number (`posts[0]`, then next update `posts[1]`, etc.). Solution itself is really simple, but took me a while to figure out. Instead of using `this.posts.push`, I simply did `this.posts = datasocket.content`. This way there's no new object and current one is being overwritten. Hope this helps someone in the future! Anyway, thank you @Belmin for your gracious help.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if anyone else is stuck on the same problem,
The "this" keyword here is referring to the parent of the Socket function.
Hence before declaring the socket listener, store this in some other variable.

let self = this;
and then use self.items.push